# Incorrect results with Sympy when utilizing (numpy's) floats

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to calculate a [velocity tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Properties_of_angular_velocity_tensors) from a time dependent rotationmatrix `RE(t)` (Namely the earth rotation at latitude 48.3°). This is achieved by determining the skew symmetric matrix `SE(t) = dRE(t)/dt * RE.T`. I am obtaining incorrect results when utilizing a float instead of a Sympy expression, as shown in the following example:

```
from IPython.display import display
import sympy as sy

sy.init_printing()  # LaTeX like pretty printing for IPython


def mk_rotmatrix(alpha, coord_ax="x"):
    """ Rotation matrix around coordinate axis """
    ca, sa = sy.cos(alpha), sy.sin(alpha)
    if coord_ax == "x":
        return sy.Matrix([[1,  0,   0],
                          [0, ca, -sa],
                          [0, sa, +ca]])
    elif coord_ax == 'y':
        return sy.Matrix([[+ca, 0, sa],
                          [0,   1,  0],
                          [-sa, 0, ca]])
    elif coord_ax == 'z':
        return sy.Matrix([[ca, -sa, 0],
                          [sa, +ca, 0],
                          [0,    0, 1]])
    else:
        raise ValueError("Parameter coord_ax='" + coord_ax +
                         "' is not in ['x', 'y', 'z']!")


t, lat = sy.symbols("t, lat", real=True)  # time and latitude
omE = 7.292115e-5  # rad/s -- earth rotation rate (15.04107 °/h)
lat_sy = 48.232*sy.pi/180  # latitude in rad
lat_fl = float(lat_sy)  # latitude as float
print("\nlat_sy - lat_fl = {}".format((lat_sy - lat_fl).evalf()))

# earth rotation matrix at latitiude 48.232°:
RE = (mk_rotmatrix(omE*t, "z") * mk_rotmatrix(lat - sy.pi/2, "y"))
# substitute latitude with sympy and float value:
RE_sy, RE_fl = RE.subs(lat, lat_sy), RE.subs(lat, lat_fl)

# Angular velocity in world coordinates as skew symmetric matrix:
SE_sy = sy.simplify(RE_sy.diff(t) * RE_sy.T)
SE_fl = sy.simplify(RE_fl.diff(t) * RE_fl.T)

print("\nAngular velocity with Sympy latitude ({}):".format(lat_sy))
display(SE_sy)  # correct result
print("\nAngular velocity with float latitude ({}):".format(lat_fl))
display(SE_fl)  # incorrect result
```

The result is:

[image: calculation results]

For the float latitude the result is totally wrong in spite of the difference of only -3e-17 to the Sympy value. It is not clear to me, why this happens. Numerically, this calculation does not seem to be problematic.

My question is, how to work around such deficits. Should I avoid mixing Sympy and float/Numpy data types? They are quite difficult to detect for more complex settings.

PS: The Sympy version is 0.7.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL; DR**

It is a bug. If you don't believe it, try this:

```
In [1]: from sympy import factor, Symbol

In [2]: factor(1e-20*Symbol('t')-7.292115e-5)
Out[2]: -2785579325.00000
```

---

Two years ago, the default value for the parameter `tol` in `RealField.__init__` was changed from `None` to `False` in commit [polys: Disabled automatic reduction to zero in RR and CC](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/commit/24649916b2c6552dd42f20f1e3b575ed8231c433#diff-8756675b7147afd7ae0afab7c6c7b936).
Later, `tol` was reverted back to `None` to fix a simplification issue, in commit [Changed tol on Complex and Real field to None](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/commit/f09894593aca1558375285dec30b7fb2879fb4c8#diff-7dc8bbd13c2a551135f6c559f707c68c).
It seems the developers didn't expect this reversion would bring some other issue.

If you modify `tol=None` at [`RealField.__init__`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/sympy-0.7.6/sympy/polys/domains/realfield.py#L48) in `realfield.py`, to `tol=False`, you will get the correct result for `SE_fl`.

```
Matrix([
[3.3881317890172e-21*sin(0.0001458423*t),                     -7.29211495242194e-5, 0],
[                    7.29211495242194e-5, -3.3881317890172e-21*sin(0.0001458423*t), 0],
[                                      0,                                        0, 0]])
```

---

The change of `tol` can explain why you've got a wrong result, but I don't thint it is the root of the issue.
IMHO, there is a deficiency in the polynomial factorization in SymPy. I'll illustrate this deficiency.
For convenience, let us do some preparation work.
Add the followings to your example.

```
from sympy import simplify, expand, S
from sympy.polys import factor
from sympy.polys.domains import QQ, RR, RealField
from sympy.polys.factortools import dup_convert
from sympy.polys.polytools import Poly
from sympy.polys.polytools import _symbolic_factor_list, _poly_from_expr
from sympy.polys.polyerrors import PolificationFailed
from sympy.polys import polyoptions as options
from sympy.simplify.fu import TR6

def new_opt():
    args = dict()
    options.allowed_flags(args, [])
    opt = options.build_options((), args)
    return opt
    
def my_symbolic_factor_list(base):
    opt = new_opt()
    try:
        poly, _ = _poly_from_expr(base, opt)
    except PolificationFailed as exc:
        print(exc)
        print(exc.expr)
    else:
        _coeff, _factors = poly.factor_list()
        print(poly)
        print(_coeff, _factors)
        return poly
```

We don't need to study the whole matrices. Let us focus on one element, element at row 1 and column 2. It has already shown the result is incorrect.

```
In [8]: elm_sy = (RE_sy.diff(t) * RE_sy.T)[1]

In [9]: elm_fl = (RE_fl.diff(t) * RE_fl.T)[1]

In [10]: elm_sy
Out[10]: -7.292115e-5*sin(0.267955555555556*pi)**2*sin(7.292115e-5*t)**2 - 7.292115e-5*sin(7.292115e
-5*t)**2*cos(0.267955555555556*pi)**2 - 7.292115e-5*cos(7.292115e-5*t)**2

In [11]: elm_fl
Out[11]: -7.292115e-5*sin(7.292115e-5*t)**2 - 7.292115e-5*cos(7.292115e-5*t)**2

In [12]: simplify(elm_sy)
Out[12]: -7.29211500000000e-5

In [13]: simplify(elm_fl)
Out[13]: -2785579325.00000
```

When we call `simplify`, in this case, it's almost equivalent to a combination of `TR6` and `factor`.

```
In [15]: expr_sy = TR6(elm_sy)

In [16]: expr_fl = TR6(elm_fl)

In [17]: expr_fl
Out[17]: 1.35525271560688e-20*sin(7.292115e-5*t)**2 - 7.292115e-5

In [18]: factor(expr_fl)
Out[18]: -2785579325.00000
```

Now, we know wrong results would be produced during the invocation of `factor()`.
Actually, `factor` is just a wrapper, the major work is done by [`_symbolic_factor_list`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/sympy-0.7.6/sympy/polys/polytools.py#L5548).

```
In [20]: _symbolic_factor_list(expr_fl, opt, 'factor')
Out[20]: (-2785579325.00000, [])
```

Let us take a look at [`_symbolic_factor_list`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/sympy-0.7.6/sympy/polys/polytools.py#L5548). The key part is:

```
        try:
            poly, _ = _poly_from_expr(base, opt)
        except PolificationFailed as exc:
            factors.append((exc.expr, exp))
        else:
            func = getattr(poly, method + '_list')

            _coeff, _factors = func()
```

We use the above `my_symbolic_factor_list` to simulate this procedure.

```
In [22]: expand(expr_sy)
Out[22]: -7.29211500000000e-5

In [23]: my_symbolic_factor_list(expr_sy)
can't construct a polynomial from -7.292115e-5*sin(0.267955555555556*pi)**2*sin(7.292115e-5*t)**2 -
7.292115e-5*(-sin(0.267955555555556*pi)**2 + 1)*sin(7.292115e-5*t)**2 + 7.292115e-5*sin(7.292115e-5*
t)**2 - 7.292115e-5
-7.29211500000000e-5

In [24]: my_symbolic_factor_list(S(1))
can't construct a polynomial from 1
1

In [25]: expr_fl
Out[25]: 1.35525271560688e-20*sin(7.292115e-5*t)**2 - 7.292115e-5    

In [26]: poly_fl = my_symbolic_factor_list(expr_fl)
Poly(-7.292115e-5, sin(7.292115e-5*t), domain='RR')
(-2785579325.00000, [])
```

By design, the constant polynomial should execute `except PolificationFailed as exc:` suite, while the other polynomials should execute `else:` suite.
`expr_sy`, which is a number after `expand()`, and `1` are both constant polynomials, thus `PolificationFailed`s were thrown.
`poly_fl` is `-7.292115e-5 * sin(7.292115e-5*t) ** 0`, namely, `-7.292115e-5`, a constant polynomial, whereas `expr_fl` is not. They were supposed to be the same polynomial, just different representation. Now they are not.
This is the **deficiency** I mentioned.

Where is the missing `1.35525271560688e-20*sin(7.292115e-5*t)**2`?
Let us recall: `tol` was reverted back to `None`, which means automatic reduction to zero in `RR` is enabled again.
`1.35525271560688e-20` was reduced to zero. Thus, `poly_fl` became a constant polynomial.
If `tol` is `False`, this won't happen.

```
In [31]: arg2 = expr_fl.args[1].args[0]

In [32]: arg2
Out[32]: 1.35525271560688e-20

In [33]: RR.from_sympy(arg2)
Out[33]: 0.0

In [34]: R = RealField(tol=False)

In [35]: R.from_sympy(arg2)
Out[35]: 1.35525271560688e-20
```

Now, we can explain why you've got `-2785579325.0`. In the `else:` suite, [`Poly.factor_list`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/sympy-0.7.6/sympy/polys/polytools.py#L3068) is called.
According to [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.Poly.factor_list):

> factor_list(f)[source]
>
> Returns a list of irreducible factors of f.

`poly_fl` is supposed to be a non constant polynomial, but it is just a number.
Thus, SymPy was tring to use a rational number to approximate `poly_fl`. The numerator is kept, while the denominator is discarded.

```
In [42]: poly_fl.factor_list()
Out[42]: (-2785579325.00000, [])

In [43]: dup_convert(poly_fl.coeffs(), RR, QQ)
Out[43]: [-2785579325/38199881995827]

In [44]: Poly([S(1.25)], t, domain='RR').factor_list()
Out[44]: (5.00000000000000, [])

In [45]: dup_convert(Poly([S(1.25)], t, domain='RR').coeffs(), RR, QQ)
Out[45]: [5/4]

In [46]: Poly((RE_fl.diff(t) * RE_fl.T)[3].args[0].args[0], t).factor_list()
Out[46]: (1767051195.00000, [])
```

I don't think we should blame mixing Sympy and float/Numpy data types. This problem is not caused by those [pitfalls](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html) SymPy mentioned.
Even a very simple factorization can produce a counterintuitive result.

```
In [47]: factor(1e-20*t-1.2345e-5)
Out[47]: -539023891.000000

In [48]: factor(S(1e-20)*t-S(1.2345e-5))
Out[48]: -539023891.000000
```

So it is a bug. Just let the developers fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed investigations. Do you happen to know, if the developers already noted that bug?

Comment: @Dietrich, someone reported it and one developer said it had been fixed in the development version. See [#9607](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9607).

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be a bug in Sympy; when I run your script on my system (Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, Python 2.7, Sympy 0.7.4.1), I get

```
lat_sy - lat_fl = -2.61291277482447e-17

Angular velocity with Sympy latitude (0.267955555555556*pi):
Matrix([
[          0, -7.292115e-5, 0],
[7.292115e-5,            0, 0],
[          0,            0, 0]])

Angular velocity with float latitude (0.841807204822):
Matrix([
[3.3881317890172e-21*sin(0.0001458423*t),                     -7.29211495242194e-5, 0],
[                    7.29211495242194e-5, -3.3881317890172e-21*sin(0.0001458423*t), 0],
[                                      0,                                        0, 0]])
```

which looks OK.

I'm not sure what to suggest: you could try an older version of Sympy than 0.7.6, or the latest revision from Github.

[In answer to comment] As to why the diagonals are non-zero, my first comment is that 3e-21/7e-5 is about 4e-17; IEEE754 64-bit ("float")
numerical precision is around 2e-16.  At 3e-21 rad/s one revolution will take 60 trillion years (about 2e21 s).  Don't worry about it.

I'm not entirely sure what is happening here, but after adding this to your script

```
def matrix_product_element(a, b, i, j):
    v = a[3*i:3*i+3]
    w = b[j::3]
    summand_list = [v[k]*w[k]
                    for k in range(3)]

    print('element ({},{})'.format(i, j))
    print('  summand_list: {}'.format(summand_list))
    print('  sum(summand_list): {}'.format(sum(summand_list)))
    print('  sum(summand_list).simplify(): {}'.format(sum(summand_list)))

matrix_product_element(RE_fl.diff(t), RE_fl.T, 0, 0)
matrix_product_element(RE_fl.diff(t), RE_fl.T, 1, 0)
matrix_product_element(RE_fl.diff(t), RE_fl.T, 2, 0)

sumlist=[sy.Float(-4.05652668591092e-5,15), sy.Float(7.292115e-5,15), sy.Float(-3.23558831408908e-5,14)]
display(sumlist)
display(sum(sumlist))
```

I get

```
element (0,0)
  summand_list: [-4.05652668591092e-5*sin(7.292115e-5*t)*cos(7.292115e-5*t), 7.292115e-5*sin(7.292115e-5*t)*cos(7.292115e-5*t), -3.23558831408908e-5*sin(7.292115e-5*t)*cos(7.292115e-5*t)]
  sum(summand_list): 6.7762635780344e-21*sin(7.292115e-5*t)*cos(7.292115e-5*t)
  sum(summand_list).simplify(): 6.7762635780344e-21*sin(7.292115e-5*t)*cos(7.292115e-5*t)
element (1,0)
  summand_list: [4.05652668591092e-5*cos(7.292115e-5*t)**2, 7.292115e-5*sin(7.292115e-5*t)**2, 3.23558831408908e-5*cos(7.292115e-5*t)**2]
  sum(summand_list): 7.292115e-5*sin(7.292115e-5*t)**2 + 7.292115e-5*cos(7.292115e-5*t)**2
  sum(summand_list).simplify(): 7.292115e-5*sin(7.292115e-5*t)**2 + 7.292115e-5*cos(7.292115e-5*t)**2
element (2,0)
  summand_list: [0, 0, 0]
  sum(summand_list): 0
  sum(summand_list).simplify(): 0
[-4.05652668591092e-5, 7.29211500000000e-5, -3.2355883140891e-5]
6.77626357803440e-21
```

The coefficients of the first summation should sum to zero, but don't.  I've managed to sort-of fake this effect in the last few lines by recreating the coefficients with lower precision (this was just luck, and probably not that signicant).  It's "sort-of" since the third value in the list (`-3.2355883140891e-5`) doesn't match the coefficient in the summand list (`-3.23558831408908e-5`), which is given to 15 places.

The Sympy docs discuss these sorts of issue here http://docs.sympy.org/dev/gotchas.html#evaluating-expressions-with-floats-and-rationals , with some suggestions on how to mitigate the problem.  Here's a straightforward variation on your code, deferring substitution of floats right to the end:

```
# encoding:utf-8
from IPython.display import display
import sympy as sy

sy.init_printing()  # LaTeX like pretty printing for IPython


def mk_rotmatrix(alpha, coord_ax="x"):
    """ Rotation matrix around coordinate axis """
    ca, sa = sy.cos(alpha), sy.sin(alpha)
    if coord_ax == "x":
        return sy.Matrix([[1,  0,   0],
                          [0, ca, -sa],
                          [0, sa, +ca]])
    elif coord_ax == 'y':
        return sy.Matrix([[+ca, 0, sa],
                          [0,   1,  0],
                          [-sa, 0, ca]])
    elif coord_ax == 'z':
        return sy.Matrix([[ca, -sa, 0],
                          [sa, +ca, 0],
                          [0,    0, 1]])
    else:
        raise ValueError("Parameter coord_ax='" + coord_ax +
                         "' is not in ['x', 'y', 'z']!")


# time [s], latitude [rad], earth rate [rad/s]
t, lat, omE = sy.symbols("t, lat, omE", real=True)

RE = (mk_rotmatrix(omE*t, "z") * mk_rotmatrix(lat - sy.pi/2, "y"))

SE = sy.simplify(RE.diff(t) * RE.T)

display(SE)
display(SE.subs({lat: 48.232*sy.pi/180, omE: 7.292115e-5}))
```

This gives:

```
Matrix([
[  0, -omE, 0],
[omE,    0, 0],
[  0,    0, 0]])
Matrix([
[          0, -7.292115e-5, 0],
[7.292115e-5,            0, 0],
[          0,            0, 0]])
```

I prefer this regardless of numerical advantages, since one may learn something from the form of the symbolic solution.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I'm still confused, why the derivative is not exactly zero in the diagonal entries.

Comment: Nice explanation. In my case this function was part of a function generator for Numpy, so I was not looking at the results at all. The idea was, that simplifying would work better, if the numerical values are substituted in.